# Captcha error with Python TikTokApi (from davidteather)

Tags: python, api, captcha, tiktok

Here is my minimalist [TikTokApi](https://github.com/davidteather/TikTok-Api) Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-

from TikTokApi import TikTokApi
import datetime

for tiktok in TikTokApi(use_selenium=True).byUsername('therock',count=10):
    print(tiktok['id'])
    print(tiktok['desc'])
    print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(tiktok['createTime']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Here is the error I get running it:

```
TikTokApi.exceptions.TikTokCaptchaError: TikTok blocks this request displaying a Captcha 
Tip: Consider using a proxy or a custom_verifyFp as method parameters
```

As mentioned in the "tip", I've also tried:

- with a free proxy chosen from this [website](https://scrapingant.com/free-proxies/)
- with the `custom_verifyFp` as the method parameter (which equals basically to the value of the `s_v_web_id` stored in my TikTok cookie)
- with both (proxy + `custom_verifyFp`)

...and I still get this Captcha error !

Any idea here ?